# how to get arguments from plugin shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm trying to access my plugin attributes but it keeps getting the default values even if i put the desired values

that's my php file

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Modern Calendar Plugin
*/
function modern_calendar_enqueue_scripts($atts) {
    // Enqueue custom CSS file
    wp_enqueue_style('modern-calendar-css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'style.css');

    // Enqueue custom JavaScript file
    wp_enqueue_script('modern-calendar-js', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'script.js', array('jquery'), '', true);

    // Extract shortcode attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'duration' => 'Default Text',
            'price' => "Call for details!", // Default text if not provided
        ),
        $atts,
        'modern_calendar'
    );

    // Sanitize text
    $duration = sanitize_text_field($atts['duration']);
    $price = sanitize_text_field($atts['price']);

    // Localize script data
    wp_localize_script('modern-calendar-js', 'calendarData', array(
        'duration' => $duration,
        'price' => $price
    ));
}
add_action('init', 'modern_calendar_enqueue_scripts');

function modern_calendar_display($atts) {
    // Extract attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'duration' => 'Default Text',
            'price' => 'Call for details!'
        ),
        $atts,
        'modern_calendar'
    );

    ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    ?>
    <div class="modern-calendar-container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col s12">
                <div class="calendar-container">
                    <div class="calendar-header">
                        <button id="prevMonth" class="btn waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons">Previous</i></button>
                        <h5 id="monthYear"></h5>
                        <button id="nextMonth" class="btn waves-effect waves-light"><i class="material-icons">Next</i></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="calendar-grid" id="calendarGrid"></div>
                    <div id="buttonContainer">
                        <span id="selectedDateText">Duration: <?php echo esc_html($atts['duration']); ?> - Price: <?php echo esc_html($atts['price']); ?> </span>
                        <button id="selectedDateButton" class="btn waves-effect waves-light">Book Now!</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered content
}

add_shortcode('modern_calendar', 'modern_calendar_display');
?>
```

this Price:   is working fine and get the value from the shortcode `[modern_calendar duration="2" price="80"]`

but when i try to access calendarData in javascript i get the default values
'duration' => 'Default Text',
'price' => 'Call for details!'
instead of the ones i put in the shortcode

```
  const duration = calendarData.duration;
  const price = calendarData.price;

  // Now you can use duration and price variables in your JavaScript code
  console.log("Duration: ", duration);
  console.log("Price: ", price);
```

console output
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsRzg.png)

Comment: Welcome! Why would you expect local variables scoped to your enqueue function be available from your local shortcode variables? There's no relationship between your shortcode and your enqueue. What you probably should do, is in the markup in your shortcode, add `data` attributes like `data-duration` and `data-price` on your elements, then in your JS `script.js` file, pass those as constants instead.